# What could I have done better with this code from a calendar?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was writing a calendar a long time ago and, coming back to the code, I've realized that it's not the best. I was fairly mediocre at programming back then.

I'm using jQuery, Mousetrap, and Hammer.js. Here is [a working example](http://8b51d1abd8.test-url.ws/) and the [code](http://8b51d1abd8.test-url.ws/main.js).

Sorry that this is long - I'm not sure if 250 lines is too long, the FAQ says "a few thousand is too long" but didn't give a specific limit. I've tried to comment it (the vast majority of comments are from today) so it's easier on the eyes, though.

```
/*jshint globalstrict: true*/

/*jshint eqeqeq:true, bitwise:true, strict:false, undef:true, unused:true, curly:true, browser:true */

var dtu = new Date(); //Always equal to [currently selected month] [day of pageload] [currently selected year] [time of pageload]
//example: if page was loaded on Mar 15, 2013 at 11:57:55, and you navigated to June 2015, dtu would be Jun 15 2015 11:57:55
var yearsShowing = false; //whether or not the years calendar ('yearendar') is showing
var dfb = 0; //how many days from the beginning of the calendar does the month start (e.g. Aug 2013 starts 4 days from the start of the calendar - on a Thurs)
var highlighted = -1; //Which cell ID is highlighted as the current date. Only applicable, of course, when on the current month.
var oldHighlighted = -1; //When the "highlighted" date was last changed, whatever its' prior value was
var isHighlighted = true; //Whether or not something on the current page is highlighted.
var go; //Tells yearOnClick whether or not it's OK to do its' thing.
var years = {i:0}; //An object that keeps track of the what date the yearendar starts.

function chYr(n) {
    //Change the year - p=previous year, n=next
    if (n === 'n') {
        refreshYears(parseInt(($('#ytext')[0].innerText).substring(0,4),10)+100);
    }
    if (n === 'p') {
        refreshYears(parseInt(($('#ytext')[0].innerText).substring(0,4),10)-100);
    }
}

function chMon(p) {
    //Change the month - p=previous month, n=next
    if (p === 'p') { 
        dtu.setMonth(dtu.getMonth()-1);
    }
    else if (p === 'n') {
        dtu.setMonth(dtu.getMonth()+1);
    }
    refreshStuff();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Only do this stuff when the document's ready...

    Mousetrap.bind('left', function() { if(yearsShowing) { chYr('p'); } else { chMon('p'); } });

    Mousetrap.bind('right', function() { if(yearsShowing) { chYr('n'); } else { chMon('n'); } });

    Mousetrap.bind('up up down down left right left right b a enter', function() {
        alert('Konami code!');
    });

    Mousetrap.bind('esc', function() {
        refreshYears(parseInt($('#ytext')[0].innerText.substring(0,4),10));
        showYears(); 
    });

    bindTouchStuff();

    resizeStuff();

    refreshStuff();

    refreshYears(2001);

    reloadBubbles();
});

function reloadBubbles() {
    //remove all dots on the page
    var x = 1;
    $.each($('.dots'), function() { 
        this.innerHTML = ""; 
        this.id = 'dots'+x;
        x++;
    });
    x=1;

    //create new dots
    for (var i=0; i<datas.length; i++) { 
        //runs once for every type of event. example: if there are two (e.g. "violin" and "homework") it would run twice
        for (x=1; x<daysInMonth(dtu.getMonth()+1,dtu.getUTCFullYear())+1; x++) {
            //runs once for each day in that month
            var dated = (dtu.getMonth()+1).toString()+'/'+x.toString()+'/'+dtu.getUTCFullYear().toString();
            //gets that day of the month; format mm/dd/yyyy (but if month or day is single char it does _not_ prefix a 0)

            if (typeof datas[i][dated] !== 'undefined') {
                //only runs if that day of the month has any of the current type of event
                $('#dots'+(x+dfb))[0].innerHTML += '<a href="#detailsModal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="$(&#39;#detailsModalLabel&#39;)[0].innerText = &#39;'+dated+' - '+datas[i].name+'&#39;; $(&#39;#detailsModalBody&#39;)[0].innerText = &#39;'+datas[i][dated]+'&#39;"><li class="'+datas[i].color+'"></li></a> ';
                //adds a dot to that day. Each dot has a link which modifies, then opens a prefab BS modal containing details of that event
                //TODO: use the HTML5 history API to change the URL and let people link to an event. Make sure to cover a scenario in which that event doesn't exist
            }
        }
    }

    //ending
    for (x=1; x<daysInMonth(dtu.getMonth()+1,dtu.getUTCFullYear())+1; x++) {
        //for each day in month
        $('#dots'+(x+dfb))[0].innerHTML = '<ul>' + $('#dots'+(x+dfb))[0].innerHTML + '</ul>';
    }
}

function bindTouchStuff() {
    console.log('Using Hammer')
    var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("all"));

    hammer.ondragstart = function(ev) { 
        if (yearsShowing) {
            if (ev.direction === "right") {
                chYr('p');
            }
            if (ev.direction === "left") {
                chYr('n');
            }
        }
        else {
            if (ev.direction === "right") {
                chMon('p');
            }
            if (ev.direction === "left") {
                chMon('n');
            }
        }
    };
    hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("all"));

    hammer.ontransformstart = function(ev) { 
        refreshYears(parseInt($('#ytext')[0].innerText.substring(0,4),10));
        showYears();
    };
}

function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

function refreshStuff() {
    setTimeout(removeHighlight,10);
}

function removeHighlight() {
    $('#day'+highlighted).removeClass('today');
    setTimeout(continueRefreshingStuff,10);
}

function continueRefreshingStuff() {
    $('#day'+highlighted).removeClass('today');

    $('#daysmonth').addClass('zoom');

    var fdom = new Date(dtu.getFullYear(), dtu.getMonth(), 1).getDay()+1; //finds first day of month

    dfb = 0; //days from beginning that month starts

    var mdtu = moment(dtu);
    $('#mtext')[0].innerText = moment.months[mdtu.month()]+' '+mdtu.year();

    for (var i=1; i<43; i++) { //43 not 42 and 1 not 0 because dates are not arrayish
        //for each of the 42 day cells

        document.getElementById('day'+i).childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText = ((i-fdom)+1); //labels days (with neg. #s, unfortunately)
        if ((i-fdom)+1<1) {
            dfb++;
            //if there are days numbered 0 or less
            var x = daysInMonth(dtu.getMonth(),dtu.getUTCFullYear()); //days in previous month
            document.getElementById('day'+i).childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText = (x+((i-fdom)+1)); //renumber dates before start of month correctly
        }
        else if ((i-fdom)+1>daysInMonth(dtu.getMonth()+1,dtu.getUTCFullYear())) {
            //if there are days numbered over the max. # of days in this month
            document.getElementById('day'+i).childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText = (((i-fdom)+1)-daysInMonth(dtu.getMonth()+1,dtu.getUTCFullYear())); //renumber dates after end of month correctly
        }
    }
    isHighlighted=false;
    if (mdtu.month() === new Date().getMonth()) {
        $('#day'+(new Date().getDate()+dfb)).addClass('today');
        oldHighlighted = highlighted;
        highlighted = (new Date().getDate()+dfb);
        isHighlighted = true;
    }

    setTimeout(unZoom, 200);

    reloadBubbles();
}

function unZoom() {
    if (!isHighlighted) $('#day'+oldHighlighted).removeClass('today');
    $("#daysmonth").removeClass("zoom");
}

function showYears() {
    $('#calendar')[0].style.display = "none";
    $('#yearendar')[0].style.display = "block";
    yearsShowing = true;
}

var yearOnClick = function () { 
    if (go===true) { 
        yearsShowing = false;
        dtu.setYear(parseInt(this.innerText,10)); refreshStuff(); 
        $('#yearendar')[0].style.display = "none"; 
        $('#calendar')[0].style.display = "block"; 
    } 
};

function refreshYears_inner() {
    if (years.this.innerText !== undefined) {
        years.this.innerText = years.start+years.i;
        years.this.onclick=yearOnClick;
        years.i++;
    }
}

function refreshYears(start) {
    go = false;

    years.i = 0;

    for (var z=1; z<11; z++) {
        years.start = start;
        years.this = this;
        $.each($('#tr'+z)[0].childNodes, refreshYears_inner);
    }

    $('#ytext')[0].innerText = start + '-' + (start+99);

    go=true;
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeStuff();
});

function resizeStuff() {
    var eye=0;
    $.each($('.day'), function() {
        eye++;
        if ((eye/2).toString().indexOf('.') === -1) { 
            this.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+($('#calheader')[0].clientWidth-7)/7+'px !important'); 
        }
        else { 
            this.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+($('#calheader')[0].clientWidth-7)/7+'px !important'); //6.985
        }
        /*if ((eye/7).toString().indexOf('.') === -1) {
            this.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+((($('#calheader')[0].clientWidth-7)/6.985)+0.1)+'px !important');
        }
        */
    });

    $.each($('.dayweek'), function() {
        this.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+($('#calheader')[0].clientWidth-6)/7+'px !important');
    });
}

window.onload=resizeStuff;
```

What could I have done better? Performance, readability, and maintainability wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to be nitpicky but here goes.

**Obviously the OP is a much better programmer today so I don't want to harp on being able to point these out. Everyone starts fresh somewhere and even I would hate to review my own old code from when I started out.**

- Since this is a calender module you should ideally make a `prototype` implementation. For e.g.

  ```
  var Calender = function () {
      this.date = new Date();
  };

  Calender.prototype.date = null;

  /* Similarly dump dtu, dfb, go, etc. here. */
  ...
  ```
- Have more descriptive variable & function names. For e.g.

  - `chYr` => `changeYear`
  - `refreshStuff` => `refreshCalendar`
  - `dtu` => `date` or `currentDate`
  - `showYears` => `isYearsShowing`
  - `highlighted` => `highlightedCellId`, and so on.
- Do not leave values `undefined` (`var go;`). Set it to `null`. You can always compare the value to `null`.
- Do not use keywords like `this` as variable names (`years.this = this;`).
- As far as possible avoid **"magic numbers"** in your code (`var z=1; z<11; z++`). Set special values as named constants somewhere in your code and use those named constants in your logic.
- Remove `console.log` from production ready code.
- Reduce the number of calls to the `$` jquery function. For e.g

  - `$('#calendar')`, `$('#yearendar')`, `$('#calheader')` seem to be called frequently. If these elements do not change once they are set on the page then populate them into memory once and access from there.

    `var $calender = $('#calender');`
- Avoid using `window.onload`. Use `addEventListener` or the jQuery `.on` API instead.
- It may not be necessary to use both `window.onload` as well as `$(document).ready`. Using `$(document).ready` should be sufficient.
- In the function `resizeStuff` there is no need for the `if` condition `((eye/2).toString().indexOf('.') === -1)` within the `each` block for `$('.day')` as both branches set the *same* attribute.

  `this.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+($('#calheader')[0].clientWidth-7)/7+'px !important');`

There could be more but I know this already may be too much to do. These suggestions would be the ideal way to keep your code maintainable, free from conflicts with other JS code/libraries and just optimized enough not to literally die on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Actually posting your code here should not require any additional comments. Everywhere you have the feeling for the need of the comment, you should check the method and variable names. Maybe even splitting a method might help to make the code more readable. (You obviously have a feeling for this at your own, so I won't post code here. But as a hint: rename all your abbreviations and don't use single letter variables )